# Flutter DropdownSearch overlay is not well positioned inside a ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-web, reorderable-list

I am working on a Flutter web app. I am trying to put a [`DropdownSearch`](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) widget inside a [`ReorderableListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html).
But when I click on the `DropdownSearch` widget to display the menu, it is not positioned correctly. It should be below, but it appears on the left top corner.

Here is a minimal code to reproduce the behavior:

`main.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            child: ReorderableListView.builder(  // <- Replace with `ListView.builder` and it works fine
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  key: Key('$index'),
                  enabled: true,
                  showSearchBox: true,
                  selectedItem: 'Option 1',
                  items: [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: 20,
              onReorder: (a, b) {},
              buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I get when I clicked on one field (highlighted in blue)
[image]

The expected behavior is this image (obtained with a `ListView.builder` instead of `ReorderableListView.builder`):

[image]

What am I missing and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that both `ReorderableListView` and `DropDownSearch` widget user `Overlay` from flutter. Internally `ReorderableListView` also uses overlay.

Comment: Yes, it is my guess too, do you have an idea of a workaround?

Comment: I tried couple of things but it didn't work like wrapping it inside a new builder widget. etc. Only wokrs when you remove the center widget from top. Basically the search overlay is calculated for the position which is top left of the screen. If you go in debug mode you can see reorderable list expands to the whole screen.